# Angular2 directive assign to template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

Is it possible to assign to view from directive?

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[foo]'
})
export class FooDirective {
   this.bar:string = "baz";
}
```

And in component's view

```
<div foo>
 bar value should be 'baz': {{bar}}.
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/To6hj9CJi1caz2pSF0RP?p=preview

I have tried many other ways like structural directives (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html)

In short: my directive should create new scope for element (like in angular 1.x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work using a template variable like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[foo]',
  exportAs: 'foo`
})
export class FooDirective {
   this.bar:string = "baz";
}
```

```
<div foo #foo="foo">
 bar value should be 'baz': {{foo.bar}}.
</div>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/k8yEhA3ad106dMd0x9I9?p=preview

Updated plnkr but without luck